# Search file for keyword, then log the rest of the line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've browsed other questions on here related to my issue but they are not working in my situation or perhaps I'm using it wrong and need a better explanation.

I'm looking to read a large file, look at the first word to see if it matches the input from the user, then if it does I would like to `console.log` the rest of the line.

**File.txt**

```
#one: This is the first line
#two: This is the second line
#three: This is the third line
etc
```

**Node Js**

```
// Take in user input

var msgSplit = userInput.split(" ");

if (msgSplit[0].startsWith("#") {

    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream('Custom_Phrases')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
        if(line.indexOf(msgSplit[0]) < 0) {
            console.log(line);
        }
    });
}
```

This works, kind of, but it returns the line after the one I want. If possible I would like for example if the user types in #one, This is the first line gets logged to the console.

Comment: `line.indexOf(msgSplit[0]) < 0` means that your user input is not found. Therefor only lines are shown, which do not match the user input. I would try `line.indexOf(msgSplit[0]) >= 0` for the if statement.

Comment: Boy I feel a bit dumb after that, thank you it works. I was confused by the user's example that I followed because the else was an error log so I figured his first statement would print the line.

Comment: It easy to see such errors if you have not written the code by yourself. I' ve made hundreds of such mistakes in the last year and had to ask friends  "Hey, what's wrong with my code?". And than they got a smile on their face, and I knew .... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line.indexOf(msgSplit[0]) < 0` means that your user input is not found. Therefor only lines are shown, which do not match the user input.

Try this:

```
// Take in user input

var msgSplit = userInput.split(" ");

if (msgSplit[0].startsWith("#") 
{
  var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream('Custom_Phrases')
  });

  lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    if(line.indexOf(msgSplit[0]) >= 0) 
    {
      console.log(line);
    }
  });
}
```